# \xpatchcmd fails in a more complicate command

Tags: macros, xpatch

I've tried to patch the `\minitoc@` command to add some additional vertical spacing after `\mtctitle` is used. (This is a question resulting from [Adjust vertical spacing between minitoc title and contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259065/adjust-vertical-spacing-between-minitoc-title-and-contents/259073#259073))

However, the neither a full inclusion of an `\if...` nor the inner branch could be patched.

To answer the question linked above I used the original command `\minitoc@`, copied it from `minitoc` package and changed the code at the relevant position then, but this isn't satisfactory.

At the moment, I can't figure out, why patching fails. As far as I can, `\minitoc@` contains effective code, nothing that defines future commands such that patching would not work.

Here is the patching and the full 'MWE'

```
\documentclass{book}    
\usepackage{minitoc}    

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newlength{\mymtcaftertitleskip}
\setlength{\mymtcaftertitleskip}{2ex} % For example

\nomtcrule


\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\minitoc@}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\columnwidth}@{}}
    \reset@font\mtifont\do@mtitc{\mtc@v\mtctitle}\\
  \end{tabular}%
}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\columnwidth}@{}}
    \reset@font\mtifont\do@mtitc{\mtc@v\mtctitle}\\[\mymtcaftertitleskip]%
  \end{tabular}%
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{\typeout{Patch failed}}  

% Here is the original definition, renamed from \minitoc to \origminitoc etc, just for comparison -- it's not used in here. 

\def\origminitoc{\@ifnextchar[{\origminitoc@}{\origminitoc@[d]}}
\def\origminitoc@[#1]{%
\global\@minitoc@used@true
\if@mtc@longext@
   \def\@tocfile{mtc\The@mtc}%
\else
   \def\@tocfile{M\The@mtc}%
 \fi
        \mtc@CkFile{\jobname.\@tocfile}
        \if@mtc@FE
        \mtcPackageInfo[I0006]{minitoc}%
           {\jobname.\@tocfile\space is empty}
        \@mtc@empty@minitoc@true
        \else
        \thispageminitocstyle
%%        \mtc@markboth{\MakeUppercase{\mtctitle}}{\MakeUppercase{\mtctitle}}%
        \beforeminitoc
        \relax\begin{samepage}%
        \if #1e\let\do@mtitc\e@mti
         \else\if #1n\let\do@mtitc\n@mti
         \else\if #1c\let\do@mtitc\c@mti
         \else\if #1l\let\do@mtitc\l@mti
         \else\if #1r\let\do@mtitc\r@mti
         \else\if #1d\let\do@mtitc\df@mtitc
        \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
        \mtc@CkStr{\mtctitle}\if@mtc@FE \let\do@mtitc\e@mti\relax\fi
        \raggedright
        \parskip=\z@%
        \reset@font\mtcfont%
        \parindent=\z@%
        \nopagebreak[4]%
        \kern-0.8\baselineskip\nopagebreak[4]%
        \par\noindent %%
        \ifx\mtc@rule\relax
         \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\columnwidth}@{}}
           \reset@font\mtifont\do@mtitc{\mtc@v\mtctitle}\\
         \end{tabular}%
        \else
         \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\columnwidth}@{}}
           \reset@font\mtifont\do@mtitc{\mtc@v\mtctitle}\\\hline
         \end{tabular}%
        \fi
        \nopagebreak[4]\null\leavevmode\mtc@zrule\\\mtc@BBR
        \leftmargin\mtcindent \rightmargin\mtcindent
        \itemindent=\z@\labelwidth=\z@%
        \labelsep=\z@\listparindent=\z@%
        \begin{mtc@verse}{\mtcoffset}%
        \c@tocdepth=\c@minitocdepth
        \leavevmode\\\mtc@BBR\vskip -.5\baselineskip
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \@ifundefined{mtc@pgno}%
  {\let\@dottedtocline\@undottedtocline}{}
  \@fileswfalse\mtc@hook@beforeinputfile
  \mtc@setform%
  \openminitoc \global\inminitoctrue
  \@input{\jobname.\@tocfile}%
  \global\inminitocfalse\closeminitoc
  \vspace{-1ex} \vspace{-\baselineskip}
  \leavevmode\mtc@strut
  \global\@nobreakfalse\endgroup
        \end{mtc@verse}%
        \kernafterminitoc
        \nopagebreak[4]\mtc@bottom@rule\null\leavevmode\\%
        \vskip-1.0\baselineskip\mtc@zrule\end{samepage}%
        \par\pagebreak[1]\vspace*{-1ex}\afterminitoc\fi}

\makeatother


\begin{document}    
  \dominitoc
  \faketableofcontents    
  \chapter{Minimum}
    \minitoc
    \section{Working}
    \section{Example}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are patching the wrong command. After the definition of `\minitoc@`, package `minitoc` saves it in `\sv@minitoc@` and changes the definition of `\minitoc@` to add stuff, when `\chapter` is not available:

```
\@ifundefined{chapter}{}{%
   \let\sv@minitoc@\minitoc@
   \def\minitoc@[#1]{{\ifundottedmtc\let\@dottedtocline\@Undottedtoclinep\fi
      \sv@minitoc@[#1]}}%
```

When used with `\sv@minitoc@`, `\xpatchcmd` succeeds.

Comment: Yes, now I see it -- I did not think of it's `\let` to something different later on

Answer (score 3):

If I do `\show\minitoc@`, I see

```
> \minitoc@=macro:
[#1]->{\ifundottedmtc \let \@dottedtocline \@Undottedtoclinep \fi \sv@minitoc@ [#1]}.
```

which means that the proposed patch cannot succeed. You are misguided by the fact that the package has a different definition for `\minitoc@`, but later on it says

```
\@ifundefined{chapter}{}{%
   \let\sv@minitoc@\minitoc@
   \def\minitoc@[#1]{{\ifundottedmtc\let\@dottedtocline\@Undottedtoclinep\fi
      \sv@minitoc@[#1]}}%
   \let\sv@minilof@\minilof@
   \def\minilof@[#1]{{\ifundottedmtc\let\@dottedtocline\@Undottedtoclinep\fi
      \sv@minilof@[#1]}}%
   \let\sv@minilot@\minilot@
   \def\minilot@[#1]{{\ifundottedmtc\let\@dottedtocline\@Undottedtoclinep\fi
      \sv@minilot@[#1]}}}
```

So `\minitoc@` keeps that definition if `\chapter` is defined, or it changes it saving the original one in `\sv@minitoc@`.

Comment: Yes, now I know, thanks to Heiko's and your efforts. I've just learned to look for `\let` later on.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Before patching a command, it's better to try `\xshowcmd` just to be sure.

Comment: Well,... eh... yes, `\xshowcmd` .. I seem to have missed it so far :D Thanks for giving me the right clue